# Why can't I run programs after closing SSH connection using setsid, nohup or disown?

Tags: bash, ssh

I am attempting to run a program 'a.o' on a remote server. To keep it running after closing SSH connection, I tried the following:

```
setsid ./a.o
```

```
nohup ./a.o
```

```
./a.o &
disown -h %1
```

None of these options seem to work, and I cannot figure out why. Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

P.S. I am using a tunnel connection to connect to the server via a jump machine. Also, this is a program that involves CUDA code running on GPU. Do these have anything to do with the issue?

Comment: You can use a Terminal Multiplexer to keep processes running after logout. Both `screen` and `tmux` are quite good, and both are in the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks a lot. I tried tmux and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The `nohup` [Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup#Overcoming_hanging) has a reference to this issue specifically:**

> Note that nohupping backgrounded jobs is typically used to avoid terminating them when logging off from a remote SSH session. A different issue that often arises in this situation is that ssh is refusing to log off ("hangs"), since it refuses to lose any data from/to the background job(s).[6][7] This problem can also be overcome by redirecting all three I/O streams:
>
> ```
> $ nohup ./myprogram > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null &
> ```
>
> Also note that a closing SSH session does not always send a HUP signal to dependent processes, such as when a pseudo-terminal has not been allocated.

As mentioned in comments, `screen` and `tmux` are perfect for this too. Personally, I prefer `tmux`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solves my problem perfectly. And tmux works for me as well.